# viewing ????? on preview emailed sent webpage instead of hebrew

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, character-encoding, hebrew, windows-1255

I have a problem when displaying page it show with ????? (question marks) instead of hebrew characters
the data in the mssql table (html) is ok 
it is only happening in a new migration site to new hosting 
The site itself look perfect in hebrew. only created pages like newsletter email, order detail email etc. that have a problem

i am working with codepage windows hebrew 1255

this in the code in the asp page that handle the writing to the html page

this code is in the header page  asp
<%@ LANGUAGE = "VBScript" codepage=1255%>
what can be the cause of this issue

please advice
thanks

Comment: What is your Mysql collation?

Comment: ntext NULL NULL UNICODE NULL NULL Hebrew_CI_AS
nvarchar NULL NULL UNICODE NULL NULL Hebrew_CI_AS
varchar NULL NULL cp1255 NULL NULL Hebrew_CI_AS

Comment: I recommend using utf-8 throughout (codepage=65001). See this for more information http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx